# HTTP POST request in controller method crashes .net core 1.1 without exception or message

Tags: c#, .net, api, http, .net-core

I'm trying to do an HTTP POST request to a server in a controller. For some reason the application just stops. There is no exception or other message.

I'm using RestEase to handle the HTTP requests. I've also tried using the HttpClient but this gives the exact same result: app crashes without message.

**Controller code**

```
 [Route("/api/[controller]")]
  [ApiValidationFilter]
  public class LeidingController : Controller
  {
    private readonly ILeidingRepository _leidingRepository;
    private readonly ITakRepository _takRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly Auth0Helper _auth0Helper;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public LeidingController(ILeidingRepository leidingRepository, ITakRepository takRepository, IMapper mapper, Auth0Helper auth0Helper, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      _leidingRepository = leidingRepository;
      _takRepository = takRepository;
      _mapper = mapper;
      this._auth0Helper = auth0Helper;
      _configuration = configuration;
    }

    //.. Some more methods that aren't relevant

    [Route("{leidingId}/createUser")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser([FromRoute] int leidingId)
    {
      var leiding = _leidingRepository.FindById(leidingId);

      //Database operations
      if (leiding == null)
      {
        return NotFound(new ApiResponse(404, $"Opgegeven leiding met id {leidingId} werd niet gevonden"));
      }

      if (leiding.Email == null)
      {
        ModelState.AddModelError("NoEmail","De gebruiker heeft geen emailadres. Kan geen gebruiker maken zonder email");
        return BadRequest(new ApiBadRequestResponse(ModelState));
      }

      //Getting some config. values from appsettings.json
      var url = _configuration["Auth0:domain"];
      var clientId = _configuration["Auth0:ni_client_id"];
      var clientSecret = _configuration["Auth0:ni_client_secret"];
      var audience = _configuration["Auth0:audience"];

      //create parameters
      var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
      {
        {"grant_type", "client_credentials"},
        {"client_id", clientId},
        {"client_secret", clientSecret},
        {"audience", audience}
      };

      IAuth0Api api = RestClient.For<IAuth0Api>(url);

      //After executing this line, the app crashes without any message.
      TokenViewModel result = await api.GetTokenAsync(keyValues);


      return Ok(result);
    }


  }
```

**IAuth0Api**

```
 public interface IAuth0Api
  {
    [Post("/oauth/token")]
    Task<TokenViewModel> GetTokenAsync([Body(BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded)] Dictionary<string,string> body);
  }
```

Comment: Try make 1.0 :             request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;  If not then take out your sniffer and find error.  See if status is 100 done or something else.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not getting a ProtocolVersion property on request objects.

Comment: HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;